# x64 linux, c++ threaded memory allocation : must i use mutex lock?

Tags: c++, memory-management, mutex

problem : if i use mutex lock in thread, allocation slows down significantly, but im getting proper allocation, therefore - proper data structure.

if i dont use mutex lock, i get the allocation job done much faster in threads, but get corrupted data structure.

this is closely related to my previous post that had fully working code too (with improper usage of mutex lock).

[c++ linked list missing nodes after allocation in multiple threads, on x64 linux; why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903721/c-linked-list-missing-nodes-after-allocation-in-multiple-threads-on-x64-linux)

ive tried three different allocators and they all seem to slow down if i use mutex lock and if i dont, data structure gets corrupted. any suggestions ?

Comment: Show your code; AFAIK the standard `malloc` or `operator new` is thread-friendly.

Comment: actual code is located here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903721/c-linked-list-missing-nodes-after-allocation-in-multiple-threads-on-x64-linux ;only changes are related only to improper usage of mutex lock.

Comment: Are you properly using locks to access shared data structures among different threads?

Comment: But since it is the changes which matter, you should show the real updated code....

Comment: If you have multiple threads updating the same linked list, you need not lock the allocations, but you MUST lock the list while inserting/removing items. If you don't, it would explain your corruption.

Comment: i was actually thinking the same thing. ill try locking only updates and report. thanks for input people !

Comment: if i dont lock allocation, i still get corruption. using tcmalloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple threads use a common data structure, e.g., some sort of memory pool, and there is at least one thread modifying the data structure, you need synchronization of some form. Whether the synchronization is based on atomics, mutexes, or other primitives is separate question.

The memory allocation mechanisms provided by the standard library (`operator new()` and `malloc()` and the other members of their respective family) are thread-safe and you don't need to do any additional synchronization. If you need to use memory allocation from a resource shared between multiple threads you create yourself you will have to synchronize even it becomes slower as a result.

Comment: well. this makes sense and i think i got my answer. do you think, object serialization/deserialization could work ? i believe, Boost had some libraries for this.